# the counterpart of std::move in boost library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am trying to use `std::move` in my codes, but the compiler (g++ 4.4) I am using does not support it. Can `boost::move` substitute `std::move` completely? Thanks.

Comment: `g++ 4.4` is very old. Consider moving to the newer version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::move` (and `boost::move` when c++0x support is enabled) is just a cast from `T&` to `T&&`. It does not actually move anything. This means that the specific type of pointer `T&&` must be supported by the compiler. GCC supports r-value references since version 4.3, so the boost version should be fine.

However, is there a reason you can't use `std::move` from `#include <utility>`?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

You just need to make sure to specify `-std=c++0x` as a compiler option in order to enable the limited c++11 support that gcc 4.4 has.

Comment: In C++03 `boost::move` it is **not just a cast**: that is why it works there. "Boost.Move is based on macros that are expanded to true rvalue references in C++0x compilers and emulated rvalue reference classes and conversion operators in C++03 compilers." See the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/doc/html/move/how_the_library_works.html)

Answer (score 8):

Yes it can

> What is Boost.Move?
>
> Rvalue references are a major C++0x feature, enabling move semantics
>   for C++ values. However, we don't need C++0x compilers to take
>   advantage of move semanatics. Boost.Move emulates C++0x move semantics
>   in C++03 compilers and allows writing portable code that works
>   optimally in C++03 and C++0x compilers.

Source:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/doc/html/move.html