# Using C++11 with move semantics - without the standard library (and with Boost.smart_ptr)

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, boost-smart-ptr, zephyr-rtos, boost-move

I’m working on embedded projects, using [Zephyr RTOS](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr) with ARM embedded microcontrollers like STM32 Nucleo series (Cortex M4/0).

Recently, due to significant C++ support improvements in the recent versions of Zephyr, I’m considering to move from C development to modern C++.

By default, Zephyr includes C standard library, but not Cpp’s STD.

Zephyr actually added optional support for Cpp’s standard library, which seems to work pretty well. However, it requires huge flash memory usage (near 65% of my microcontrollers flash memory, without my code!).

So I’m trying to search for alternative ways to use modern C++ without the actual standard library (including the memory/utility headers).

I’ve considered to use [Boost.smart_ptr](https://github.com/boostorg/smart_ptr) for smart pointers, but I’m wondering how I should use move semantics (std::move) In my case.

Should I use [Boost.Move](https://github.com/boostorg/move) module? Even though I’m using C++1x and not C++0x?

Should I implement move semantics by myself using [direct cast from T& to T&&](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761709/5856345)?

Comment: You can just implement `std::move` yourself in one line... Ok, you need `remove_reference` too and maybe want to do some formatting. But if all you need from the standard library is `std::move` then there's not going to be any problem.

Comment: Boost (and virtually any CPP code) relies on STD i.e. includes std headers.

Comment: I would rather avoid STD, exceptions & RTTI

Comment: @IgorR. If I'm not wrong Boost have fallbacks in their internal implementations if the STD headers isn't included. I've already succeeded to use Boost.DI without STD, gonna also try smart_ptr & move but I've noticed they also have fallbacks in the source code...

Comment: @P__J__ Of course I'm avoiding any anti embedded mechanisms like exceptions and RTTI. But smart pointers seems to be valuable for my needs so I rather not give up on this.

Comment: @IgorR I'm afraid you're wrong, because Boost doesn't implement `::operator new()`, and `shared_ptr` dynamically allocates its control block.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks, maybe I'll just implement this semantic myself. Anyways, do you know if there are any downside for using Boost.Move with C++1x?

Comment: @IgorR. Actually Zephyr themselves does implement new operator (using libc/newlib internally) so this is not a big deal in my case.

Comment: Either std::move() or boost::move() is just a typecast to &&.   If your library implements `operator new`, it implements the standard library (or maybe some subset of it).

Answer (score 1):

I've just found what caused the huge flash usage of the STD.

In my case, it was inclusion of the `<iostream>` header (used for `std::cout`), without it flash usage is reasonable enough, even with std containers.

So I guess it solved my issue, I can use C++ STD for my purpose now.

(using `<iostream>` in embedded environment [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59268950/5856345) anyways, for printing just use `printf`)